# Should I use past tense for this sentence because of precise time (this morning)?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, past-simple

I **'ve already drunk** three coffees this morning *(I **drank** three coffees this morning)*

*morning has already gone* (it is lunch time now)

Comment: Good distinction. Yes, I'm inclined to agree that "*I drank three coffees this morning*" is more appropriate since its now afternoon. "*I've already drunk three coffees this morning*" leaves the door open for having another cup of coffee in the morning, which is wrong since its afternoon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases they can be used interchangeably but they describe slightly different things.

The present-perfect tense (“I’ve already drunk .”) describes your *present* state as a result of the past action. (eg. “I've already drunk three coffees this morning so I’m wide awake.”)

The simple-past tense describes what happened in the past. (eg. “I went to the café and drank three coffees this morning.)